# Additional Line read in for loop - Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a strange issue -- this is my code:

```
for /f %%a in (D:\Balaji\filepath\output5.txt) do call :Sub1 %%a
:Sub1
echo file name is %1
if exist %1 (
echo File %1 has arrived update the DB..
) else (
echo Waiting, no update to DB.
echo We have to check if the SLA has breached.
)
```

The file `output5.txt` doesn't contain any trailing white-spaces or newline, but when I run this, for loop detects an additional line - output is something like this:

```
file name is D:\folder\test.txt
File D:\folder\test.txt has arrived update the DB..
file name is D:\folder\file.csv
File D:\folder\file.csv has arrived update the DB..
file name is D:\folder\test1.txt
Waiting, no update to DB.
We have to check if the SLA has breached.
file name is D:\folder\test2.txt
Waiting, no update to DB.
We have to check if the SLA has breached.
file name is
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

As you can see in the last two lines -- it's perhaps reading an empty line?

How can I fix this?

Content of `output5.txt`:

```
D:\folder\test.txt
D:\folder\file.csv
D:\folder\test1.txt
D:\folder\test2.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f %%a in (D:\Balaji\filepath\output5.txt) do call :Sub1 %%a
GOTO :EOF
:Sub1
```

A label in batch is simply a place-marker. It does not end a "procedure". Batch just charges through line by line until it reaches a `goto` or `exit` or end-of-file.

'goto :eof` where the colon is *required* means 'go to end-of-file' - the label is understood, and does not have to be inserted by the programmer

Comment: Thanks very much, so dumb of me to miss the EOF! :D